# Draw path of divs between two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to position n divs in between two absolute positioned divs? Im creating some sort of map and would like to draw footprints between two points. I was wondering if i could calculate coordinates of first and second div and determine how many footprints (with fixed width) would go in between and than somehow absolute position them with top and left position.

I don't know how to put this together in jQuery or Javascript.. Any ideas??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Instead of divs you could try SVG, since it allows you to create and manipulate objects via DOM, apply CSS, it has a coordinate system which you can scale, position, translate, as well as animate (via SVG, JS or CSS). Since you are making a graphic it's probably a better solution.

Comment: can you provide a codepen or jsfiddle to have a live example of your trouble ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is what I came up with:


## Fiddle

There can be as many pairs of points as you wish, one has the class `first`, the other having the class `second`, and they will be paired with steps thanks to the following:

```
var f = $('.first');
var s = $('.second');

f.each(function(i) {
    var f2 = f.eq(i);
    var s2 = s.eq(i);
    var xdist = s2.position().left - f2.position().left;
    var ydist = s2.position().top - f2.position().top;
    var dist = Math.sqrt(xdist*xdist + ydist*ydist); // Pythagoras
    var numOfSteps = Math.round(dist / 50) - 1;
    var stepX, stepY;

    for (var l = 0; l < numOfSteps; l++) {

        stepX = xdist/(numOfSteps+1)*(l+1) + 
                f2.width()/2 + f2.position().left;

        stepY = ydist/(numOfSteps+1)*(l+1) + 
                f2.height()/2 + f2.position().top;

        $('<div></div>').addClass('step').appendTo($(document.body))
            .css('left', stepX + 'px')
            .css('top' , stepY + 'px');
    }
});
```

It's pretty much understandable without any comments, but if you can't figure out something, feel free to ask.

The number of footprints is calculated here:

```
var numOfSteps = Math.round(dist / 50) - 1;
```

and so to change the amount of footprints, change the number 50 to something else (the bigger the number, the less footprints).

Glad to help, was fun coming up with this ;)

Comment: Nice solution thank you very much on that! Simple math behind scenes :) I have one more challenge for you though. What if i would like to turn each footprint towards second div with css transform property. Is there a way to calculate angle between two divs and than rotate each div appropriately?? Thanks !

Comment: Yeah I can pull that off, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JUReE/3/)
I've used CSS arrows, you can also use an image

Comment: Thank you weirdo, really appreciate your effort :) I see now that it's all about math :)